# Closed geodesic minimizing properties

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Considering closed geodesics on a compact manifold M of even dimension, what does it mean to say that a curve (any closed geodesic) is locally energy minimizing but not globally ? For simplicity, say $M=S^2$. Intuitive answers would help rather than equations/semantics.

**EDIT**: What I am looking for is an example of a closed curve on a manifold, which is a local geodesic(locally energy minimizing) but not globally. I understand that $S^2$ might be a bad example because intuitively I think all geodesics are local and global minimizers of energy (please correct me If I am wrong) but in any case, I think a torus might be a great example to find one, especially in light of this article:

http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf

Comment: Every non-trivial closed geodesic starting and ending at some point $p$ fails to be an energy minimizer, in the sense that the constant path at $p$ has strictly smaller energy. If that's not the type of example you're seeking, could you please clarify the question? :)

Comment: That's right. But I am looking for an example that is locally energy minimizing.In the example you point out, if you could clarify to where the local and global parts would fit in, I would appreciate it.  I came across this assertion in one of the books I was reading and cannot seem to get past it without understanding the intuition behind it.

Comment: Every geodesic in a Riemannian manifold is [locally energy-minimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry). (That is, if $\gamma:[0, 1] \to M$ is a sufficiently small piece of geodesic, then $\gamma$ minimizes energy among all piecewise-smooth paths joining $p = \gamma(0)$ and $q = \gamma(1)$.) Here's a familiar example: If you want to walk across the room, you have at least two choices: 1. Walk across the room, or 2. walk all the way around the earth "in the other direction". Both paths are geodesic (locally energy-minimizing), but one path has smaller energy.

Answer (score 0):

Shall give an example. Take a cone, start at point near vertex and wind a string around tautly, returning to the same point after it nears a minimum distance at vertex and gets back.

Repeat the same with starting angle 90 degrees to the generator, the string will just go away from vertex along a divergent path of no-return.

Both are geodesics. The  first one is closed, minimizes associated energy.The energy of the diverging geodesic is more than the first. Accordingly it is necessary to distinguish  the local energy minimizing path from the other global possibilities. That is to say, local minimum is minimum among all energy/length minimizing paths.

Comment: I am sorry, can you be a little more clear about "after it nears a minimum distance at vertex and gets back" ?

Comment: To get an intuitive feel for geodesics one has to work with hands. Take a cellulose tape , make a cardboard cone and keep sticking the tape straight to wherever it leads you. Else draw  lines on the flat development of a cone and roll it to a cone. All the geodesics do not go the same way.

Comment: I got the idea, Thanks. But the point of my question was to find examples of closed curves which are local minimizers of energy but not global minimizers.

Comment: @Naramsimham: Please refer to my edit for more info.